# Display subtitle with Android Media Player?

Tags: android, media-player, android-video-player, subtitle

I am using this snippet to open a video using default Android Video Player:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("http://my.video/link.mp4"), "video/mp4");
startActivity(intent);
```

Now I want to display subtitle on the video, my subtitle is provided with a url, example `http://my.subtitle/link.srt`. I think there would be something simple like this:

```
intent.putExtra("subtitle", "http://my.subtitle/link.srt");
```

But it doesn't seem to be simple like that.

Could anyone show me how to do it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: There's no guarantee you'd be able to do this with a separate file as not every Android video player app will handle subtitles in the way you hope. When you use `ACTION_VIEW` it will attempt to start whatever video player app the user has chosen to be their 'default'.

Comment: @Squonk yeah, I just think about that too. So with the Android default player (Video Player), is there any option for this? Where can I find more information to do want I want?

Comment: I think about another solution: display a subtitle activity floating in the screen, above the Video Player. I'm not sure if it is possible. @Squonk, you have any idea?

Comment: Some media players support subtitles. For example I use MX Player (available from Google Play) but I think it only uses SRT files stored on the device so your code would have to download the SRT before starting the video player. If you want to display the subtitles yourself then you could write your own code based on MediaPlayer / VideoView with a "floating" overlay but that gets more complicated.